# Why does my application freeze on lock?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, locking

Following scenario: I have a class with 2 methods: `StartLoop` and `StopLoop`.

`StartLoop` starts a loop that is polling some data and write it to a data structure, after it, it raises an event. This is getting repeated until `StopLoop` is called.

`StopLoop` stops the loop and clears the data structure.

Now it can happen, that while the loop is writing something to the data structure `StopLoop` gets executed and clears the data structure. To prevent that simultanous access, I do a lock.

Unfortunately, when I call `StopLoop` after the loop was started, my application hangs at the lock.

My simplified code:

```
class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Event;

    private bool _runLoop;
    private List<int> _fooList = new List<int>() { 0 }; //my data structure

    static readonly object _myLocker = new object();

    public void StartLoop()
    {
        _runLoop = true;

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (_runLoop)
            {
                lock (_myLocker)
                {
                    Event(this, new EventArgs()); //call event
                    _fooList[0] = 1; //do some writing on structure
                }
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    public void StopLoop()
    {
        lock (_myLocker) //<--- application hangs here
        {
            _runLoop = false; //end loop
            _fooList = null; //clear structure
        }
    }
}
```

On my Window (it's a WPF application) i register my event to following Handler:

```
void foo_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //append an "a" for each loop
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { uxDisplayTest.Text += "a"; }));

  //a "DoEvent" for WPF to keep the window responive
  Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
}
```

**Why is my application freezing when I am calling `StopLoop`? And how can i solve it?**

Comment: Presumably because StopLoop is invoked from the UI thread, and the lock blocks it from continuing until start loop finishes

Comment: Where are you calling `StopLoop()`? Anyway, NEVER keep something locked while you call arbitrary code via raising an event. Who knows how long that arbitrary code will take to return? It might, for example, show a dialog box and wait for the user to close it...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I call `StopLoop()` and `StartLoop()` with 2 different buttons. The idea behind the code is to wait until the handlers are finished (otherwise my event is too fast so that the handlers cant process all events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `ManualResetEvent` to signal the thread it should stop. That way you don't need to lock in `StopLoop`:

```
private Thread _myThread = null;
private ManualResetEvent _stopThread = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void StartLoop()
{
    _myThread =  new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (!_stopThread.WaitOne(1))
        {
            Event(this, new EventArgs()); //call event
            lock (_myLocker)
            {
                _fooList[0] = 1; //do some writing on structure
            }
        }
    });
    _myThread.Start();
}

public void StopLoop()
{
    stopThread.Set();
    _myThread.Join();

    // Why clear the structure? Rather re-init when restarting the threads
    //_fooList = null; //clear structure
}
```

Please be aware that this may still block in case the event you're firing does anything in the context of the UI thread. Maybe you don't need to `Join` at all. Personally, I'd have the thread pause a bit within its loop to lower CPU usage.

You will notice I've also moved the lock so only access to the array is covered. It's a bad idea to put the call to the event in the lock. This is bound to cause deadlocks sooner or later. Also, the rule is to lock resources as shortly as possible.

---

On your comment: *The idea behind the code is to wait until the handlers are finished (otherwise my event is too fast so that the handlers cant process all events).*

This can not happen. All attached event handlers will be executed in `Event(this, new EventArgs());` and only after that the next line of code will be executed. Also, locking doesn't change this behaviour at all.

Comment: A thread pause can be set by increasing the value of the `WaitOne` parameter, right?
I need `Join` because of the `Dispatcher.Invoke` in this case. I guess a `Join` with timeout is good to fit both cases (the case with UI thread context and the case without).
To "clear the structure": I simplified it, in the real application I clear some values in the structure (means I re-init it).
I added a `_stopThread.Reset();` on `StartLoop()` to make it restartable.

Comment: No. The wait is done using `Thread.Sleep(ms);`. The timeout parameter for the `WaitOne` indicates the maximum time the call should wait for the handle to be set. I wouldn't use this as a pause.